# How to setup different tabSize for template section with volar vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting, volar, prettyhtml

We were using `vetur` vscode extension to handle vue single components formatting.
We configured it to use prettier for js, stylus supremacy for style and prettyhtml for template section.
For prettyHtml we configured it to use 2 spaces tab size. Wherease js and stylus use 4 spaces.

Now we need to use `volar` vscode extension since vetur is deprecated. We didn't find a way to have this kind of specific configuration.
volar use default vscode formatters. All our tries to setup using `volar.config.js`, `volar-prettyhtml` plugins does not work. We certainly miss something but we can't guess what.

Any of you success to have such (prettyhtml as html formatter) configuration using volar extension ?